# Файлы .bak, умышлено делать кто может?

Tags: php

Уже не первый раз пользователи обращаются с проблемой что выдает ошибка 404. Я захожу на сервер а файл почему то стал например restore.php.bak . У меня вопрос, можно ли как то это делать умышленно, ну типо sql иньекции, только кто то извращается с файлом.

Comment: а чем Вы пользетесь? можно поподробнее услышать о сайте. Возможно Вы пользуетесь Битриксом каким-нибудь или ещё чем то?

Comment: @МихаилРебров сайт не большой, движок с 0 писал я. Он одностраничный, регистрация, оплата, происходит через ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.php.bak - файл бекапа оригинального файла. обратитесь к хостеру с вопросом, почему такие файлы появляются. нет смысла делать бекап когда гадишь), да и "каку" так тоже не скрыть. Это особености работы вашего сервера.

Comment: Обратился, ответили что когда кто то долбит файл, их проактивная защита берет оригинальный файл и переименовывает, например index.php.bak .

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кто-то получил доступ к твоєму серверу и  удаляет файлы,  bak файл, это копия твоего файла, когда ты его изиеняешь, может скрипт какой-то делает или вирус(удаляет)

Comment: Доступ 100% никто не получил. Получается каким то хакерским способом если на пример отправить 100 000 пост запросов на этот файл сделать его .bak нельзя?